# RabbitMQ with Docker and Rancher produces "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"-errors in the management UI

Tags: docker, user-interface, rabbitmq, rancher

As the title suggests. When I deploy my RabbitMQ image via Rancher I get the following errors in the management interface. I have no clue what is causing this problem (even after extensively searching the internet).

[image: screenshot]

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM rabbitmq:3.7.7-management-alpine
COPY definitions.json /etc/rabbitmq/
COPY rabbitmq.config /etc/rabbitmq/
RUN chown rabbitmq:rabbitmq /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config 
/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json
CMD ["rabbitmq-server"]
```

*rabbitmq.config*

```
[
    {rabbit, [
    {loopback_users, []}
  ]},
  {rabbitmq_management, [
    {load_definitions, "/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json"}
  ]}
].
```

*definitions.json*

```
{
    "bindings": [],
    "exchanges": [],
    "global_parameters": [],
    "parameters": [],
    "policies": [],
    "queues": [],
    "rabbit_version": "3.7.7",
    "topic_permissions": [],
    "users": [{
            "hashing_algorithm": "rabbit_password_hashing_sha256",
            "name": "username1",
            "password_hash": "hash1",
            "tags": "administrator"
        }, {
            "hashing_algorithm": "rabbit_password_hashing_sha256",
            "name": "username2",
            "password_hash": "hash2",
            "tags": "administrator"
    }
    ],
    "vhosts": [],
    "permissions": []
}
```

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: "2"

services:
    rabbitmq:
        image: myname/imagename
        hostname: rabbitmq
        ports:
            - 15672:15672
            - 5672:5672
```

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that current user has enough rights to access Exchanges and Queues tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Please, clear your browser's cache after you do.